# I need to put an NSString variable in another string inside the initWithSource function, but I don't know how

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, macos

I need to put an NSString variable between another string code to get the 'pathToSerialDevice' variable between the other code. Like this:

```
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc]
                initWithSource:@"Tell application \"Terminal\" \n\
                                do script with command \"screen %@", pathToSerialDevice, "\" in front window\n\
                                end tell"];
```

And my pathToSerialDevice string is taken from a text field

```
pathToSerialDevice = [NSString stringWithFormat:_pathTextField.stringValue];
```

When I display it in the Log, it works, I do it so:

```
NSLog(@"Your path is %@", pathToSerialDevice);
```

How to do the same, but in the NSAppleScript? It doesn't work now and I have no idea how to do it. Please help me.

P.S.
I have Xcode 6.1 on OS X 10.10 and it's an OS X app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initWithSource:` takes a regular string, not a format string. [Read these docs on the difference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html).

The easiest thing to do is to just make another string:

```
NSString *pathToSerialDevice = [NSString stringWithFormat:_pathTextField.stringValue];
NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tell application \"Terminal\" \n\
                                              do script with command \"screen %@ \" in front window\n\
                                              end tell", pathToSerialDevice];

NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
```